# How to give button different function on same form depending on content ID

Tags: php

i'm still a relative noob, any help would be greatly appreciated...

i have set an unpublished project as a template page, "add new project" is clicked it directs it to the pre-made template. as all new/edit projects are based on the same form  it has a "save" button with a "save as new project" dropdown. can anyone help me, code wise, make the button function as "save" on all projects except the template ID and "save new project" on only the template ID?? 
i have searched everywhere - really stuck on this one..

the current coding for the dropdown is below - (the ID number for the template is ID=8 )

```
protected function getToolbar()
 {
  $options = array();
  $user    = JFactory::getUser();

  $create_ms = $user->authorise('core.create', 'com_pfmilestones');
  $create_task = $user->authorise('core.create', 'com_pftasks');


  $options[] = array(
  'text' => 'JSAVE',
  'task' => $this->getName() . '.save');

  $options[] = array(
  'text' => 'Save as new project',
  'task' => $this->getName() . '.save2copy',
  'options' => array('access' => ($this->item->id > 0)));


  PFToolbar::dropdownButton($options, array('icon' => 'icon-white icon-ok'));


  PFToolbar::button(
  'JCANCEL',
  $this->getName() . '.cancel',
  false,
  array('class' => '', 'icon' => '')
   );

  return PFToolbar::render();
   }
 }
```

Comment: how can you distinguish between new and existing project ?

Comment: all projects have an ID number, the one i want to use as the template is identified as ID:8

Comment: you asked a question in javascript/jquery and you have posted PHP code.

Comment: its my first post - my appologies, will post in a different section

Comment: is ID:8 is the id attribute of some div for template ? what is ID:8 ? please post html/js code. i will solve this as if i get ID:8 then i change caption of button as save as new else save. and put some hidden filed in html and assign value such as `newproject` `extproject` according to template selection. i get data for this input field in php _post method and then depends upon its value i write further logic.